# Cauchy sequences the space of binary sequences with the metric $\sum 2^{-k}|x_k-y_k| $

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let's consider the following metric space $(X,d)$, where:

$X = \{ \ x = (x^1,x^2,x^3,\ldots,x^k,\ldots)\ \mid \ x^j \in \{0,1\}\ \forall j \geq 1\ \}$

$d(x,y) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}} | x^{k} - y^{k} |$

This is the space of all sequences consisting of $1$'s and $0$'s. This is a metric space, it's easy to see why.

I'm examining the Cauchy sequences in this metric space, and it seems to me that the Cauchy sequences in this space are constant. Meaning, I think that the Cauchy sequences $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in this metric space, are those sequences which satisfy $x_{n}^k = x_{m}^k$ for all $n,m \geq N$, for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: I had a hunch I was wrong. What I meant to say, is that these are the sequences that are eventually constant, after some index $N$ (so I thought)

Comment: Consider the sequence $(1,0,0,\dots), (0,1,0,0,\dots), \dots$, so that always this one moves one place further down, then the distance from index $N$ between any sequences is below $\frac{1}{2^N}$ and thus it is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. What would this sequence converge to? I understand that it would get closer to something, would it be the element consisting of only zeros?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: I see! Yes this I understand, but in this space all Cauchy sequences do converge. I guess I am most confused about is inferring what the limit would be, only given that a sequence Cauchy.

Comment: For a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, so far I have been able to show that for every $p \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{n}^k = x_{m}^{k}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq p$, and for all $n,m \geq N$.

Comment: Actually, I was now also quite confused about this space, but what you say is sound. So if you want to know an entry of the limit sequence you just have to check any element of the sequence for sufficiently large $N$ and look at its entry at this position. I don't think that one can say more.

Comment: @KoliG You may want to delete the confused (and potentially confusing) first comment. (This space is not at all like $[0,1]$, it is a Cantor-type set. )

Answer (score 1):

[KoliG](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545998/cauchy-sequences-in-this-metric-space#comment3148245_1545998) gave an example of a nonconstant Cauchy sequence: let $x_n$ be the sequence with $n$th entry $1$ and other entries $0$. Since $d(x_n,x_m)=2^{-n}+2^{-m}$ for $n\ne m$, this is a Cauchy sequence. It converges to the zero sequence.